# administration skills required on Windows operating systems from a SAN admin point of view

Tags: windows-server-2003

Can someone tell me the administration skills required on Windows operating systems(windows 2003) from a SAN admin point of view.
Would really appreciate if some one can elaborate a little on this and provide an useful link.
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a minimum you'll need to know how to rescan the scsi bus, align disks, assign drive letters, format volumes, create partitions and extend partitions.